# authHash from another language to python

Tags: python, api

The following is the api guide from bold360 website

```
accountId=[your account id]
apiSettingId=[your API setting id]
apiKey=[your API key]

auth="$accountId:$apiSettingId:$( date +"%s" )000"
authHash="$auth:$( echo -n "$auth$apiKey" | openssl dgst -sha512 | sed 's/^.* //')"
```

> Questions: I don't really understand the last two lines of code mean.
>
> 1. $( date +"%s" )000
>
> 2.( echo -n "$auth$apiKey" | openssl dgst -sha512 | sed 's/^.* //')
>
> what does it look like if this is in Python?

I wrote this in python

```
def millsecond(dt):
    epoch = dt.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    return (dt-epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0

def makeAuth():
    # seconds = time.time()
    timestamp = int(millsecond(dt.now()))
    token = str(accountId) + ":" + str(settingID) + ":" + str(timestamp) + api_key
    hash = hashlib.sha512(token.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    auth = str(accountId) + ":" + str(settingID) + ":" + str(timestamp) + ":" + str(hash)
    return auth

authHash = makeAuth()

url_runReport = "https://api.boldchat.com/aid/[AccountID]/data/rest/json/v1/runReport?auth=[auth]&ReportType=0&Grouping=chat_type&FromDate=2023-01-27T00:00:00-08:00&ToDate=2023-01-27T23:59:59-08:00"
response_runReport = requests.get(url_runReport)
runReport_data = response_runReport.json()
```

my result always shows

> {'Status': 'error', 'Message': 'Expired authorization'}

My guess is authhash is not correct. Can someone teach me how to code the authHash in python? Thanks

Comment: You did well: the two codes are almost equivalent, and produce the same result given the same parameters (i.e. if you fake the timestamp to the exactly same number). The only difference is that the timestamp in Python is not rounded to a second (i.e. does not necessarily end with `000`), but it would be a very weird API if it had a problem with that. Is your system time correct? I would want to make sure [`ntpd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) is running...

Comment: Hi @Amadan, not sure how to check ntpd. I use this [w32tm /query /status] in cmd, it shows some record. I think it's running. Also I'm at PST time zone, will this conflict my code?

Comment: Basically, is your system time correct? `ntpd` is just a good way to ensure that, but not strictly needed. Looking at your `millsecond` function again, it does not seem to be correct. Current epoch time in Python, equivalent to `date +%s`, is `time.time()`; multiply by 1000 for milliseconds. The error in your code seems to be mixing UTC and non-UTC datetimes. Can you try replacing `millsecond` with `time.time() * 1000`?

Comment: @Amadan I tried `time.time()*1000` , it was not success. the output shows with decimal. `1675267337.5043018` , then I use `int` to parse it, and  it works!! Great thanks.